# The same sql statement works differently in Jasper and pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I face a problem with SQL query in JasperSoft studio. I am trying to get records from posgreSQL database from between two dates. 
I use this statement:

```
SELECT spent_on FROM time_entries WHERE spent_on BETWEEN date '2014-01-01' AND date '2014-11-1' ORDER BY spent_on DESC
```

or simpler but with the same problem:

```
SELECT spent_on FROM time_entries WHERE spent_on BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-11-1'
```

also using < and > ends the same way.

spent_on column is defined as: spent_on date NOT NULL.

When I run this query in pgAdmin I get all rows I expected to receive, however when I try the same statement in JasperSoft Studio I get none.

I found out that I can get some rows when I change range to: "between date '2012-01-01' and date '2014-11-1'"  and the last entry I get is from 2012-05-29.  (where in database last one is from 2014-11-12)

Database store data for Redmine.

***SOLVED***

Reason: different schema used in Jaspersoft Studio and pgadmin.

Comment: So, is your RDBMS Redmine or Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the `date` keyword. Jasper may be understanding this the wrong way. (Just a shot in the dark.) String literals are cast to `date` automatically in this context:

```
SELECT spent_on
FROM   time_entries
WHERE  spent_on BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-11-1'
ORDER  BY spent_on DESC;
```

I would also have suggested `ORDER  BY spent_on DESC NULLS LAST`, but you say the column is defined `NOT NULL`, so not applicable. [Details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/939860)

Also, the observed behavior (not getting the latest rows) would suggest you are not connected to the same database or running the query with a different **`search_path`**, so you end up with a **different table of the same name in a different schema**. Details:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777)

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @GregG

The different schemas were used in Jaspersoft Studio and pgadmin